# Pyarrow subset data on date time column

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I've been trying to read and subset a parquet file using  pyarrow read_table.

This is the code

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


s3_uri = "Path to s3"
fp = pq.read_table(
            source = s3_uri,
            use_threads = True,
            filters = [('Date_Time' ,'>=','2022-07-08'),('Date_Time' ,'<', '2022-07-09')]
            )
print(fp.to_pandas())
```

I get the following error on executing the above.

**pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Function greater_equal has no kernel matching input types (array[timestamp[us]], scalar[string])**

Comment: I think you need to cast '2022-07-08' to pyarrow.timestamp("us")

Comment: Yeah, It got fixed after casting !! Thanks for your time

Answer (score 6):

It requires a `pa.TimestampScalar`, which you can create with [`pa.scalar`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.scalar.html#pyarrow.scalar)

```py
import datetime

fp = pq.read_table(
    source="hello.parquet",
    use_threads=True,
    filters=[
        ('Date_Time', '>=', pa.scalar(datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-07-08', "%Y-%m-%d"))),
        ('Date_Time', '<', pa.scalar(datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-07-09', "%Y-%m-%d")))
    ]
)
```

Comment: nice one ! to be more precise it works because python.datetime default is in microseconds, you can check [pyarrow.compute](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.strptime.html) methods to be safe